# Resize not contiguos partitions

Tags: partitioning, gparted, unallocated

These are my partitions:

[image]

I would like to resize sda4 by 15Gbi and assign them to sda2. Can I do it? How?

Comment: Why? sda2 has plenty of space, it appears? Your swap partition is probably excessive. You could delete it, and create a /swapfile (assuming later versions of Ubuntu) on sda4, edit /etc/fstab, then move sda4, then use Windows Disk Management app to move sda3 and extend sda2.

Comment: @heynnema I need to create a +50Gb VM on sda2. Maybe I can do what you say with the swap partition, but how can I move the unallocated space from not contiguos sdaX?

Comment: You only have about 70GB of unused space so a 50GB VM will make things tight. However it can be done, just use a live CD/USB and GParted for the Linux partitions and as @heynnema says Microsoft Disk Management for the Windows partitions. It’s not unusual to get a very small bit of unallocated space even when you specify using all the space available. I guess this is due to block alignment but I don’t know for sure. You only have 1MB unallocated though.

Comment: Then you either need a larger SSD/HDD, or add a second SSD/HDD to do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)